# Double parameter is equal to 0.0 after the division

Tags: java

```
int p = 6;
System.out.println(_nums.size() + ", " + p);

64, 6
```

Why the `result` is equal to 0.0 instead of 0.9?

```
double result = (_nums.size() - p)/_nums.size();
```

Comment: How to use non-integer division?

Comment: The type of the entire expression `(_nums.size() - p)/_nums.size()` is `int`. You then assign that to a `double`. You must convert an operand to a `double` early enough: `(_nums.size() - (double)p)/_nums.size()`.

Comment: or `(_nums.size() - p) * 1.0 /_nums.size();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're currently doing is dividing integers, and then casting the result of that division to a double. So the operation is equivalent to something like this right now:

```
int intermediate = ((_nums.size() - p)/_nums.size()); // This can only be an int (e.g. 0).
double result = (double) intermediate; // Now this is just the double value of that int (0.0).
```

To do "true" division with integers, just cast one of them to a `double` before you divide. This will force the division operation to use floating-point arithmetic, since it has floating-point (`double`) inputs.

```
double result = (_nums.size() - p) / ((double) _nums.size());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force the use of floating-point math like so

```
double result = ((_nums.size() - p)/((double)_nums.size()));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double result = (_nums.size() - p)/_nums.size();
```

is same as

```
double result = (double)  (int)(_nums.size() - p)/ (int) _nums.size();
which equals
      =(double) 6/64;
      =(double)  0   
      =0.0
```

Comment: to get 0.9, you have to do as Henry Keiter says...